# Getting the id of a repeater field in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I am faceing a problem. I have a image view that contains a repeater. What i want to do is when the last image is shown the site needs to be redirected but i dont know how to get the current field that is shown. I was thinking that i could make a variable that holds the current id and compare it every time a new image is shown. And if the new images id is lower than the one in the other variable it has to redirect.

At the moment i dont really have any code to post because i really don know how to solve this. Hope some of you can help.

This is the code for the repeater on the html site

```
<div id="imgBack" runat="server" class="row" style="background-color: black;">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="fotorama" data-arrows="false" data-maxheight="750" data-allowfullscreen="native" data-loop="false" data-ratio="1024/750" data-nav="false" data-autoplay="5000" data-click="false" data-swipe="false" data-stopautoplayontouch="false" data-transition="crossfade" data-shuffle="true" data-fit="contain">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="repImgs" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repImgs_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="imgs" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Images/{0}", Eval("FileName")) %>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is what i got on the back end so far

```
 protected void repImgs_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemIndex == repImgs.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect("FinishedSession.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the repImgs.Items is 0 but when i debug, and hover over repImgs i can see that it finds the two items that are on the session.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last item in your repeater you could use `ItemDataBound`

```
protected void MyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemIndex == MyRepeater.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it might work, the only problem now is that it newer gets inside the nested if statement for some reason

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I have posted the code for the repeater on the html site and the code on server site

Comment: That's very weird because it seems to be working on my local dev. I'm assuming you're binding the repeater in the `Page_Load` event? I've used `ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>'` instead of `String.Format()` for the image Url. How are you retrieving the images?